# Is the graph of $(\cos x)(\sec x)$ discontinuous?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I suspect that the graph of $\cos x\times \sec x$ must be discontinuous because,at $x=90^0$ the function becomes $\frac{0}{0}$ so it must be undefined or just point to nothing on the graph at that point.

But,Desmos and Wolfram gives me the plot of the function as a straight line passing through $(0,1)$ without any discontinuation.

So,which one is correct?Am I wrong in thinking that $\cos x\times\sec x=1$ is not true for all values of $x$?

**Wolfram-**

[image]

**Desmos-**

[image]

Note:-Same goes for $(\sin x)(\text{cosec} x)$ and $(\tan x)(\cot x)$.

Comment: It might be better to format the function as $(\cos x)(\sec x)$ or simply $\cos x \sec x$ rather than using the $\times$ operator, to avoid giving the impression you are forming a Cartesian product of two sets.

Comment: You could try $y=\dfrac{x}{x}$ [in Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%3Dx%2Fx) to see that it does not always capture the obvious

Comment: @AakashKumar It's not discontinuous, it is undefined. Those are two different things.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry , you are correct .

Comment: @Arthur: I would want to avoid saying that $f$ is discontinuous at $\pi/2$. However, the sentence "It is not the case that $f$ is continuous at $\pi/2$" is true.

Answer (score 7):

To simplify things, consider the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{x}$. For all $x\not=0$, $f(x)=1$. But, $f(0)$ is undefined. Thus, $f$ is equivalent to $1$ except at $x=0$ where it is undefined. In the same way, $\cos x\times\sec x=\frac{\cos x}{\cos x}$ is $1$ for all $x$ such that $\cos x\not=0$. I.e., for all $x$ except $x=\pm \frac{\pi}{2},\pm\frac{3\pi}{2},\ldots$. On a graph you can indicate this by interrupting the line $y=1$ with hollow circles at these points indicating that the function is undefined there.

Comment: This is the true answer. Just as the more famous (and counterintuitive) example $\frac 1x$, the function doesn't have any discontinuities. It just has points where it's not defined, and is continuous everywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you mean.

If you are considering $\cos(x) \sec(x)$ to be the partial<sup>*</sup> function whose values are given by mechanically inserting a value for $x$ and computing the indicated sequence of operations, then yes, its graph should have removable discontinuities at every $x = (2n+1) \pi/2$.

(note that there are no discontinuities in $x \in [-1,1]$, but that's moot since you get the same behavior from wolframalpha on an interval that does contain a discontinuity)

*: Throughout the post, I follow the common abuse of notation and say "function" when I mean "partial function".

---

However, that is often not what one means by such notation. One example is that one might instead intend to *continuously extend* the resulting function, in the same way we might say $x/x=1$.

Here, we are treating $\cos$ and $\sec$ as mathematical objects in their own right, and performing arithmetic *on those objects* rather than on their values.

We can define multiplication of two functions $f$ and $g$ to be the function defined in the following way:

- First compute the function $h$ defined by pointwise multiplication.
- Let $S$ be the set of *removable discontinuities* of $h$
- The product of $f$ and $g$ is the function given by

$$ x \mapsto \begin{cases} h(x) & x \notin S \\ \lim_{y \to x} h(y) & x \in S \end{cases} $$

With this definition of product, $\cos(x) \sec(x) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

How would you prefer for these graphing programs to illustrate the hole? With a hollow dot? With a break in the curve/line? Then how wide should the dot be? How wide should the break be? Any positive width is perhaps inherently misleading.

But more fundamentally, how should these programs know there is a hole there in the first place? If at some stage, it tries to evaluate at $x=\pi/2$, then it would be reasonable for the software to recognize there is no output there. But there is a continuum of $x$-values to display, and the software can only make finitely many calculations before it plots. So it is bound to simply never have looked directly at the $x$-values corresponding to some of the holes. Instead it will have calculated at some $x$-value to the left, and some other tot he right, and just interpolated a small line segment between them.

Comment: WolframAlpha has access to a sophisticated symbolic manipulation package; it's not limited to simply plugging in values and hoping for the best!

Comment: How do you show that discontinuty in a graph?

Comment: @Hurkyl But it is still limited. Find some function $f$ with zeros all over the place in a pattern that has not been studied and put into some specific package, and then it will certainly fail to find the holes in $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}$. Furthermore, missing the holes can be precisely the fault of the symbolic manipulation. When $\cos(x)\sec(x)$ is symbolically simplified to $1$, that's how holes get missed.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, **it depends what you mean**.  Here, $\cos x$ and $\sec x$ are both meromorphic functions on $\mathbb C$.  Their product as meromorphic functions is the meromorphic function $1$ on $\mathbb C$.  So, when you consider them not pointwise, but instead as meromorphic functions, the product has no discontinuities.

Comment: What is $\mathbb C$?I am not too confident in complex analysis...so can you make your answer more informative...it will help me a lot..thanks...

Comment: From your answer and the other answers,I am a little confused....you said that as it is a *meromorphic* function,it must be $1$...so,graph must be straight line...other answers say that it is not $1$ as the function is discontinuous as $\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos x\sec x\neq f(\frac{\pi}{2})$ as it is not defined there...So,which one should I learn myself or teach others?$\cos x\sec x=1$ or $\neq1$ or both are equally correct?